# How to randomly pick a element from a set in c++?

Tags: c++

Given a set of integers:

```
std::set<int> itemInTest;
```

There are about 4000 integers in this set and I want to loop 100 times, each time it can pick 100 different elements from the set randomly. 
In addition, all the integers are positive.

how to randomly pick one of them each time? I know there are many answers in stackoverflow, but some are too complex and some are not so random.

Comment: Can you describe the set?  Is it large, small?  Is it dense or sparse?  Negative or only positive?  Duplicates allowed?  If duplicates are allowed, do duplicates need to show up in the output more often or the same frequency as non-dupes?

Comment: @JohnZwinck I will edit it immediately

Comment: @deviantfan That’s actually a pretty terrible way of solving this problem, and potentially introduces substantial bias. It’s also horribly inefficient with a `std::set` (but I’m not sure there’s an efficient way).

Comment: @KonradRudolph: There is an efficient way with trees in general, but not using the public `std::set` interface.

Comment: @KonradRudolph On second thought you're right :/ Shouldn't post anymore about 5 minutes after waking up (at least my mental state)

Answer (score 8):

First, put your items into a vector since you will need to randomly access them many times:

```
vector<int> items(itemInTest.begin(), itemInTest.end());
```

Then, if you need 100 items and don't want to pick the same one twice, you may as well just shuffle the whole thing:

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 gr(rd());
shuffle(items.begin(), items.end(), gr);
```

Now just take the first 100 elements.  If you want them in a set again:

```
set<int> result(items.begin(), items.begin() + 100);
```

Or you can use any output container type you like--including vector.

You can do the `random_shuffle` step again until you finish your 100 overall iterations.

If you don't have C++11, you can use `std::random_shuffle()` instead of `std::shuffle()`, noting that the quality of randomness may be reduced.  Then you don't need `std::mt19937`, just:

```
random_shuffle(items.begin(), items.end());
```

Comment: It’s pretty disappointing that the C++ standard library doesn’t have a partial shuffle. Shuffling the whole range to pick m < n numbers is pretty wasteful. On a different note, **do not use `random_shuffle`**. I cannot upvote the answer because it recommends a deprecated technique with a bad random number generator. Use C++11’s random functionality, the old way is objectively bad.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I've updated my answer to be C++11 first, and noted the old/maybe-worse way at the end.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I tried your answer but got two errors: 
error: 'random_device' is not a member of 'std'
         std::random_device rd;
         ^
 error: 'mt19937' is not a member of 'std'
         std::mt19937 gr(rd());

Comment: @yobichi: Are you using C++11 or are you stuck on an older version?  If you are on C++11, you just need to #include the right headers.  If not, you can use `random_shuffle` instead as per the last part of my answer.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Sorry I am new to c++ so I am afraid that I do not sure if I include the right headers or not. I have copy my headers to the answer below. Do you mind take a look and see if I am right. I think I am not using c++11.

Comment: @yobichi: You must `#include <random>` as documented here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device - if you are indeed not using C++11 then see the last part of my answer for what to do.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I can not include <random> as I am told that "This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options."

Comment: The last part of the answer should read "If you don't have C++11, get it". The support is so widespread as of now it really doesn't make sense to keep churning out legacy code.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: I mostly agree with you, but some people refuse to quit working for companies that refuse to quit using C++98.  I would bet that more than 50% of C++ users are not "allowed" or "able" for some reason to use C++11 at all.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I am using other's code, so I have no say.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [Fisher–Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle):

Something like:

```
// Fisher–Yates_shuffle
std::vector<int> FisherYatesShuffle(std::size_t size, std::size_t max_size, std::mt19937& gen)
{
    assert(size < max_size);
    std::vector<int> b(size);

    for(std::size_t i = 0; i != max_size; ++i) {
        std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, i);
        std::size_t j = dis(gen);
        if(j < b.size()) {
            if(i < j) {
                b[i] = b[j];
            }
            b[j] = i;
        }
    }
    return b;
}
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/OKc3vS)

then from indexes, you take value from your set (which should be transformed into `vector` for random access).